# In C# how can I do a Dictionary of generics?

Tags: c#, generics

Lets say I have Generic class `Foo<T>`.

What i want to do is create a singleton for each of a variety of T, and then quickly retrieve them by T later on.

in pseudocode

```
STORE new Foo<int>
STORE new Foo<MyClass>

GET instance for MyClass  ->  returns the Foo<MyClass> created above.
```

In Java I'd make a dictionary that had Type for the key and `Foo<*>` for the value.

What is the equivalent magic in C#?

Comment: In an entirely typesafe manner? If not, use `Dictionary<Type, object>`.

Comment: Well,Im trying to be as type safe as possible.  There may just be some hard limits on that.

Comment: Sounds a bit like dependency injection with singleton lifestyle :P

Answer (score 9):

```
Dictionary<Type, object> Dict = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

void Store<T>(Foo<T> foo)
{
    Dict.Add(typeof(T), foo);
}

Foo<T> Retrieve<T>()
{
    return Dict[typeof(T)] as Foo<T>;
}
```

Comment: Why cast? Not necessary...

Comment: Now necessary :) But Dict's definition could be <Type, Foo<Type>> so there wouldn't be need for it :)

Comment: Foo<Type> is not the same as Foo<T>. Type is a concrete class - the one that describes the C# datatype.

Comment: The cast is necessary, by the way. The type of `Dict[xxx]` is `object`.

Comment: I deleted my answer and upvoted yours. Mine was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways a method may be given a type: as a `Type` parameter, or as a generic type parameter.  In the former case, if the generic class `Foo<T>` inherits from a base class (e.g. `FooBase`) which is not generic in type T, one may use a `Dictionary<Type,FooBase>`.  The `FooBase` class can include all the members (perhaps as `abstract` or `virtual`) of `Foo<T>` whose signature doesn't depend upon `T`, so code which is given a `Type` object for an arbitrary type but does not have a generic type parameter will be able to do with a `FooBase` anything that could be done without having a generic type parameter.  Note that if one has a `Type` object and wants to use it as though it were a generic type, one will generally have to use Reflection and construct either a delegate or a generic class class instance with the type parameter filled in; once one has done that, one may use the second approach below.

If one has a generic type parameter available (e.g. one is writing a method `T GetThing<T>(whatever)`, one may define a static generic class `ThingHolder<T>` with a static field `T theThing`.  In that case, for any type `TT`, `ThingHolder<TT>.theThing` will be a field of type `TT`.  One will be able to do with this field anything that can be done with a `TT`.